# Problems with nested loop, recurrence in second loop

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

The problem I have encountered is: I have a nested loop needed to do parallel. To simplify, code is like:

```
    do i=1,nelectron

     trigger=0

     do step=1,nt
        if(step==1)then
            call maxwellian(vx1_new,vy1_new,vz1_new,vt)       
        end if
        vx1_old=vx1_new
        vy1_old=vy1_new
        vz1_old=vz1_new
        x_old=x_new
        y_old=y_new

        call moveparticle(vx1_old,vy1_old,vz1_old,dt,step)
        call boundary(x_new,y_new,step+1)

        if(mod(step-1,100)==0)then
           ntrap((step-1)/100)=ntrap((step-1)/100)+1
        endif

        if(trigger==1)then
           energy_out=energy_out+energy
           go to 10
        endif
        call energy_track(x_new,y_new,vx1_new,vy1_new,vz1_new,step)
        call track_current(x_new,y_new,vx1_new,vy1_new,vz1_new,step)

        call collision(melectron,mh2,vx1_new,vy1_new,vz1_new,step+1)

     end do
     10   call datadump(step)
   enddo
```

How do assign `i` to different threads, while on each threads `j` loop is done orederedly.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. What is that needs to be done in order? Each loops on `j` while they are independent to the the `i` indexes? The whole `i,j` pairs should be kept ordered? Please be more specific in your example.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, to be clear, what I mean in order is that the calculation in the `j` loop is in recurrence relation, for example: `a(j)=f(a(j-1))`. I need to know the value in `j-1` to calculate the value in `j` step.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. And unless there's something more that you didn't show, your algorithm isn't parallelizable. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: @Gilles For `j` loop I cant do parallel I understand, but can I do the parallel on `i` loop? What I want is assign `i` to different threads while on each thread `j` loop is done normally.

Comment: Then you'll mess-up your `a` array as the various threads will update the same `a(j)` at the same time. And you cannot privatize `a` as each value `a(j)` at iteration `i+1` depend of the value `a(j)` at iteration `i`. Your recurrence is both in `i` and `j`. No chance of a parallelization here.

Comment: @Gilles no `a(j)` is independant of `i`, recurrence is only in `j` loop. What about I just privatize `a()` at the beganning then it will run ok?

Comment: No, here `a(j)` depends on `i`; just imagine for `i=1` having `a(j)=j` and `f(x)=x`. Then for `i=2` `a(j) = j-1`, and for `i` being whatever, `a(j)=j-i+1`. So `a(j)` depends of `i`.

Comment: @Gilles oh I see, sorry for the bad example, in my actual model recurrence in `j` is independent of `i`, then I guess I can privatize and run parallel on `i` loop then.

Comment: possibly. But maybe not as simply as this. Show the actual code.

Comment: @Gilles I have updated the code I actually used.

Comment: Ok, if that is parallelizable, then you'll need to spend a bit of time to see which variables need to be declared `private`, `firstprivate`, etc. And also i looks like you're using quite some global variables... So look at some possible use of `threadprivate`... Good luck with that.

Comment: @Gilles Ok. thanks for the help.